# Android what method is called when back button is pushed in a Preference Fragment

Tags: android

I have a preference fragment and it has an option to open another preference fragment that allows the user to select contacts. When I push the back button the values in the first preference fragment don't refresh. What method is invoked when I press the back button?

Comment: Are you talking about `onBackPressed()`?

Comment: Activity's onBackPressed gets invoked which internally invokes Fragment's popBackStackImmediate method.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, you want to override [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29)